# Initialize function with standard input

Tags: f#

I am facing a problem that leave me disoriented, since it should be a pretty basic procedure. I am learning how to build simple console applications with F#, but I cannot figure out how to pass an integer as standard input to the program. Please consider:

```
open System

let square x = x * x

[<EntryPoint>]
let main (argv :string[]) = 
    printfn "The function will take an input and square it" 
    printfn "%d squared is %d" 12 (square 12)
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
0
```

How can I pass the value to `printfn` and `square` the way I can do in C with:

```
int main(){
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("\nThe value of variable i is %d.\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to adapt `let x = Console.ReadLine()` to get integers, but no appreciable results. The [documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Input_and_Output) I consulted, mainly consider string inputs. I am afraid I am missing something important for properly comprehend the basic of F#. Any suggestion, in this sense, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `int.Parse()` is your friend

Comment: Thanks @JohnPalmer, I will do a little of practice on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ReadLine ()` will return a string. As mentioned by @JohnPalmer, it needs to be parsed to an int. The following program should give you the basic idea:

```
let rec input () =
    printf "Input: "
    match Core.int.TryParse (stdin.ReadLine ()) with
    | true, i -> i
    | _ ->
        printfn "Invalid input, try again"
        input ()

let square x = x * x

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    printfn "The function will take an input and square it"
    let i = input ()
    printfn "%d squared is %d" i (square i)
    0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this straightforward example.